# Is .html URL suffixing better for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, yahoo

When you click to read a Yahoo news article, the URL is suffixed with .html

Why Yahoo does not opt for pretty URLs instead?
Is .html URL suffixing better for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.html and seo-url/ both looks same for search engines as I know,if them both readable by human.

Example :

```
my-seo-url.html

my-seo-url/

my-seo-url
```

Here is a nice article to read.

https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls

Answer (score 2):

No. It makes no difference. On the contrary, one could argue that shorter and cleaner urls are better than adding the file extension like in this case.

[This is the same thing that Google says in this vlog.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMIW3i37YeY)